# CMD to PowerShell, run an exe with a XML

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm porting my scripts over to PowerShell from CMD and used to use the following:

```
start /wait Setup.exe /silent /play "path\filename.xml"
```

I however am not able to convert this over to PowerShell. How do you run an executable with arguments like `/silent` and `/play`?

Comment: `start -wait Setup.exe '/silent /play "path\filename.xml"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file runs synchronously (i.e. doesn't return before completion) you could simply run the executable:

```
setup.exe /silent /play 'C:\path\to\filename.xml'
```

optionally with the call operator:

```
& setup.exe /silent /play 'C:\path\to\filename.xml'
```

If you need to wait for a program that detaches itself from the console you can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet (alias `start`):

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath setup.exe -ArgumentList '/silent', '/play', 'C:\path\to\filename.xml'
```

or (for short)

```
start -Wait setup.exe '/silent', '/play', 'C:\path\to\filename.xml'
```

Comment: I tried PerSerAI answer and it worked but was going to ask why. I was thinking what cmdlet I would use that would allow me to run exes with an argumentlist.

Thanks for the indepth answer!