# How do you run batch files from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Traditionally, I have been able to do something like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "\\server\Install.bat" -Wait
```

However every time I run that, a command prompt will flash on the screen then disappear and the installer never kicks off. But if I navigate to the batch file location and double-click it to run it manually it runs just fine. I swear I have done this before, but is Powershell unable to run batch files?

EDIT: Batch file code:

```
SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe /SITE_TOKEN=(sitecode) /SILENT
```

sitecode obviously contains the proper site code for our facility.

EDIT 2: Additional info:

My `Start-Process` contains the FQDN path to the batch file. I have also tried the `&` with the FQDN to the batch file as well as attempting the CLI command right inside Powershell. All yield the same results. I have also tried including `start SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe` as well as `start /wait SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe` into the batch file with the same results.

I can still run the batch file manually by double clicking it and it works great. But no matter what I try to do to call it from Powershell, it fails with **"SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"**

EDIT 3 as it would take too many characters to respond in the comments:

[CMD to PowerShell, run an exe with a XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186009/cmd-to-powershell-run-an-exe-with-a-xml) was linked as a possible troubleshooting step. I have tried the following all including the FQDN:

```
\\server.domain.com\SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe /SITE_TOKEN=xxxxx /SILENT

& \\server.domain.com\SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe /SITE_TOKEN=xxxxx /SILENT

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "\\server.domain.com\SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe" -ArgumentList '/SITE_TOKEN=xxxxx', '/SILENT'

Start-Process -Wait "\\server.domain.com\SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe" '/SITE_TOKEN=xxxxx', '/SILENT'
```

All of which point directly to the .exe file with the FQDN in the search and all yield the following: **"SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"**

I also tried renaming the file to **SentinelAgent.exe** but it just returns the same error with the updated name.

I have also tried copying the entire directory down to C:\Temp and running the .bat/.exe command there - same error message.

Comment: Add a `PAUSE` to the end of your batch file so the window stays open and you can see what the error message is.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your powershell code.  So the problem is within your batch file. You will need to provide the contents of your batch file.

Comment: You should not use `Start-Process` at all for CMD/Batch files. Just call them like you would in CMD. ... or use the call operator `&` and quotation marks if the file names have spaces.

Comment: Says "SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command". But double clicking the batch still works?

Comment: @Olaf I have tried using the ```&``` to call the batch file directly with the same results.

Comment: @Olaf Because the argument list is only for CLI. The "/SITE_TOKEN=". My ```Start-Process``` contains the FQDN path to the batch file. I have also tried the ```&``` with the FQDN to the batch file as well as attempting the CLI command right inside Powershell. All yield the same results. I have also tried including ```start SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe``` as well as ```start /wait SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe``` with the same results.

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186009/cmd-to-powershell-run-an-exe-with-a-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186009/cmd-to-powershell-run-an-exe-with-a-xml)

Comment: @Olaf Good post, but did not resolve the issue. Still persists. Does anyone know if Powershell has an issue running batch files from a network location? That could be the only other reason I could think this is such an issue other than my Powershell being messed up.

Comment: @Olaf Please read the original post... I have included the entire Powershell line but used ```\\server\Install.bat``` instead of the entire FQDN for privacy purposes and the entire error message is included under "EDIT: 2" talking about the internal or external command. All of the code is in the original post as well as the error message. I don't know what more I can provide for you.

Comment: When you double-click on your batch file, if that is its entire content, the current directory will be the same as the batch files location, and therefore your executable `SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe`, would need to be in the same directory too, somewhere in `%Path%`, or an application path location in the registry. My guess is its in the same location as the batch file. When you run your code from powershell, the current directory will be that of your powershell session. I'd therefore suggest that your batch file code is changed to `"%~dp0SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe"`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using `Start-Process`, include the `-WorkingDirectory "A:\Folder"`, _(i.e. the location of `SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe`)_, and leave the batch file untouched. This may however present you issues, whould you wish to run `Start-Process` as administrator though, so i'd offer the batch-file change as the primary route to take.

Comment: @Compo I have tried specifying the working directory in some testing cases. I have recently tried some other batch files and now they are not working so I think this issue is more than just the one. I have reboot my computer just to be sure, but I think I might have to test on some other computers in the area. As of right now, running any batch file from Powershell is a no-go.

Comment: What I've told you are facts, anything else is your omission, or error, and we cannot assist you with those. You've also been told that you absolutely do not need, and should not be using a batch file for this task at all. An exectuable file can be invoked in exactly the same manner from a PowerShell Prompt/powershell.exe instance, as it is in a Command Prompt/cmd.exe instance. All you are doing is introducing more steps and therefore more opportunity for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C <executable path and args>'
```

This is specific to running command line commands.  An executable should not be an issue since the OS knows what to do with that type of file.  As others have pointed out a .cmd or .bat file in this case provides no value and will create obscurity.

In this case the statement would be:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command 'cmd.exe /C \\server\SentinelAgent_windows_v4_4_2_143.exe /SITE_TOKEN=xxxxx /SILENT'
```

Comment: This! This completely solved my issue. Thank you very much!